# Javascript subscription result children lists are undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

In my dashboard application I have the following data structure:
Project -> Dashboard -> etc. .So this means a `project` object inherits a list of `dashboard` objects. When the user logs in the project data get loaded and observed so that different components can access the project data. But now when I am trying to access a specific dashboard of a project in my subscription I am getting an undefined error. My subscription looks as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.dataService.projectData
      .subscribe((project: Project) => {
        this.project = project;
        console.log('Project', project);
        let d: Dashboard = project.dashboards[0];

        this.currentDashboardId = project.dashboards[0].id;
        this.dataService.changeCurrentDashboardId(this.currentDashboardId);
        this.currentSheetId = project.dashboards.find(x => x.id === this.currentDashboardId).sheets[0].id;
        this.dataloaded = true;
    });
}
```

The printed log 'Project' even displays the object correctly. But one line later when accessing a dashboard I am getting `undefined`. Can't explain why. Maybe anybody of you guys know and can tell me why. I appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you received the correct data?

Comment: Do you mean that `project.dashboards[0]`  is null?

Answer (score 0):

Use `first()` operator to be sure that the data revived, console.log is a bit tricky, it's not show what happened in correct time,
your code can be like:

```
this.dataService.projectData
.pipe(first())
.subscribe((project: Project) => {
  // your code is here
});
```

you can use Filter() as well to wait for specific value in your response
something like

```
this.dataService.projectData
.pipe(filter(project) => project.somevalue !== undefined)
.subscribe((project: Project) => {
  // your code is here
});
```